# Installed MySQL on my Mac and it's removed global npm, gulp etc. Steps to save npm?

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, gulp, bin

I have just installed a machine-version of MySQL on my Mac and all of a sudden my npm and gulp commands no longer work.

When I check my `/usr/local/bin` directory there's no Gulp or Npm. It's just two MySQL directories.

Does this mean I now need to reinstall all of my global dependencies or have I missed something?

Comment: How did you install this mysql?

Comment: Using the GUI from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html#downloads

Comment: If that's something the installer did then that installer's really broken. How did you install Node? Via Homebrew? If so, you may want to install MySQL through Homebrew as well.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been through Homebrew. My MAMP setup for my main projects isn't running MAMP's MySQL now, too. This has been an interesting Thursday.

Comment: I'd re-install Node with the [Mac installer here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). Maybe that would be more persistent. Maybe the problem is between MySQL and Hombrew.

Comment: Could yoy maybe be inside your mysql user ?¿??¿?¿?¿   PLz , get out the session you are using now.

Answer (score 1):

It became clear that due to the two methods for installing packages must have caused some conflicts with where packages were being saved...

Using a GUI to install MySQL, Brew for Node and NPM for Gulp *could* be the issue.

I just had to reinstall Node and all my other global dev dependencies. I also installed MySQL through Brew so they're all controlled through one manager.

Comment: Just ran into this myself... installed mysql with the downloadable package and it wiped out everything.